# SQL Server - PIVOT - two columns into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I saw many questions about PIVOT for a single column, each question more complex than other, however, I could not find anything like what I need.

To be honest, I don't even know if pivot will help me in this situation.

Let's say I have this data on my source table:

```
SELECT '1' as 'RowId', 'RandomName1' as 'First', 'RandomLast1' as 'Last'
UNION
SELECT '2' as 'RowId', 'RandomName2' as 'First', 'RandomLast2' as 'Last'
UNION
SELECT '3' as 'RowId', 'RandomName3' as 'First', 'RandomLast3' as 'Last'
UNION
SELECT '4' as 'RowId', 'RandomName4' as 'First', 'RandomLast4' as 'Last'
UNION
SELECT '5' as 'RowId', 'RandomName5' as 'First', 'RandomLast5' as 'Last'
```

Maximum of 5 rows with the first name and last name.
The value of the columns First and Last will be random.

```
RowId First       Last
----- ----------- -----------
1     RandomName1 RandomLast1
2     RandomName2 RandomLast2
3     RandomName3 RandomLast3
4     RandomName4 RandomLast4
5     RandomName5 RandomLast5
```

I was trying to pivot this data to something like this:

```
First1      Last1       First2      Last2       First3      Last3       First4      Last4       First5      Last5
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
RandomName1 RandomLast1 RandomName2 RandomLast2 RandomName3 RandomLast3 RandomName4 RandomLast4 RandomName5 RandomLast5
```

For example:
I don't have any problem if columns First5 and Last5 are NULL because there are only 4 rows.

```
First1      Last1       First2      Last2       First3      Last3       First4      Last4       First5      Last5
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
RandomName1 RandomLast1 RandomName2 RandomLast2 RandomName3 RandomLast3 RandomName4 RandomLast4 NULL        NULL
```

Can anyone give me a little help? 
Thanks.

---

Solution based on Sheela K R answers:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(First1) as 'First1',  MAX(Last1) as 'Last1',
    MAX(First2) as 'First2',  MAX(Last2) as 'Last2',
    MAX(First3) as 'First3',  MAX(Last3) as 'Last3',
    MAX(First4) as 'First4',  MAX(Last4) as 'Last4',
    MAX(First5) as 'First5',  MAX(Last5) as 'Last5'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN RowId = 1 THEN [First] END as 'First1',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 1 THEN [Last] END as 'Last1',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 2 THEN [First] END as 'First2',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 2 THEN [Last] END as 'Last2',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 3 THEN [First] END as 'First3',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 3 THEN [Last] END as 'Last3',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 4 THEN [First] END as 'First4',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 4 THEN [Last] END as 'Last4',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 5 THEN [First] END as 'First5',
        CASE WHEN RowId = 5 THEN [Last] END as 'Last5'
    FROM
    (
        SELECT '1' as 'RowId', 'RandomName1' as 'First', 'RandomLast1' as 'Last'
        UNION SELECT '2' as 'RowId', 'RandomName2' as 'First', 'RandomLast2' as 'Last'
        UNION SELECT '3' as 'RowId', 'RandomName3' as 'First', 'RandomLast3' as 'Last'
        UNION SELECT '4' as 'RowId', 'RandomName4' as 'First', 'RandomLast4' as 'Last'
        --UNION SELECT '5' as 'RowId', 'RandomName5' as 'First', 'RandomLast5' as 'Last'
    ) test
) test2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can get the result that you want.  Similar to [@Sheela K R's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250732/426671) answer you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression but it can be written in a more concise way:

```
select 
  max(case when rowid = 1 then first end) First1,
  max(case when rowid = 1 then last end) Last1,
  max(case when rowid = 2 then first end) First2,
  max(case when rowid = 2 then last end) Last2,
  max(case when rowid = 3 then first end) First3,
  max(case when rowid = 3 then last end) Last3,
  max(case when rowid = 4 then first end) First4,
  max(case when rowid = 4 then last end) Last4,
  max(case when rowid = 5 then first end) First5,
  max(case when rowid = 5 then last end) Last5
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/026ec/2).

This could also be written using the PIVOT function, however since you want to pivot multiple columns then you would first want to look at unpivoting your `First` and `Last` columns.

The unpivot process will convert your multiple columns into multiple rows of data.  You did not specify what version of SQL Server you are using but you can use a `SELECT` with `UNION ALL` with `CROSS APPLY` or even the `UNPIVOT` function to perform the first conversion:

```
select col = col + cast(rowid as varchar(10)), value
from yourtable
cross apply 
(
  select 'First', First union all
  select 'Last', Last
) c (col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/026ec/3). This converts your data into the format:

```
|    COL |       VALUE |
|--------|-------------|
| First1 | RandomName1 |
|  Last1 | RandomLast1 |
| First2 | RandomName2 |
|  Last2 | RandomLast2 |
```

Once the data is in multiple rows, then you can easily apply the PIVOT function:

```
select First1, Last1, 
  First2, Last2,
  First3, Last3, 
  First4, Last4, 
  First5, Last5
from
(
  select col = col + cast(rowid as varchar(10)), value
  from yourtable
  cross apply 
  (
    select 'First', First union all
    select 'Last', Last
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (First1, Last1, First2, Last2,
              First3, Last3, First4, Last4, First5, Last5)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/026ec/4)

Both give a result of:

```
|      FIRST1 |       LAST1 |      FIRST2 |       LAST2 |      FIRST3 |       LAST3 |      FIRST4 |       LAST4 |      FIRST5 |       LAST5 |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
| RandomName1 | RandomLast1 | RandomName2 | RandomLast2 | RandomName3 | RandomLast3 | RandomName4 | RandomLast4 | RandomName5 | RandomLast5 |
```

Comment: You nailed it. I like the concise way, I'm using the SQL 2012.

Comment: @navossoc The concise way is definitely easier since you have a `rowId` that can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([uid] int, [name] varchar(4), [diseaseid] int, [intensity] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([uid], [name], [diseaseid], [intensity])
VALUES    (1, 'xxxx', 2, 'low')
    (1, 'xxxx', 1, 'high'),

;

SELECT MAX([uid]) AS [uid]
       ,MAX([name]) AS [name]
       ,MAX([diseaseid1]) AS [diseaseid1]
       ,MAX([intensity1]) AS [intensity1]
       ,MAX([diseaseid2]) AS [diseaseid2]
       ,MAX([intensity2]) [intensity2]
FROM 
(
    SELECT [uid], [name]
    , CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN NULL ELSE [diseaseid] END AS [diseaseid1]
    , CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN NULL ELSE [intensity] END AS [intensity1]
    , CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN NULL ELSE [diseaseid] END AS [diseaseid2]
    , CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN NULL ELSE [intensity] END AS [intensity2]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [uid], [name], [diseaseid], [intensity], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [uid] ORDER BY Name) AS rn
        FROM #Table1
    ) T
) T
GROUP BY [uid], [name]
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but your answer helped me a lot to get there. Thanks!